# Python parallel array generation

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I wanted to generate parallel 2 two arrays, i. e. `x1` and `x2` for further analysis(compare  max value element from x1 with max value element from x2).
The beginning of program looks like this

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np


while true:

   x1 = np.random.normal(0, 500, 12500)
   x2 = np.random.normal(0, 500, 12500)

   if(x1...x2): #condition comparing elements from array x1 and x2
      break

print('Number found)'
```

and I tried to rewrite it like this

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np

def gen():

   np.random.normal(0, 500, 12500)

while true:

   x1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=gen, arg=())
   x2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=gen, arg=())

   x1.start()
   x2.start()

   x1.join()
   x2.join()

   if(x1...x2): #condition comparing elements from array x1 and x2
      break

print('Number found)'
```

But program does not generate random arrays x1, x2 parallel. Thank you for you help.

Comment: you are aware that `gen` does not return anything, nor does it assign to a global variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x1` and `x2` are in your second example Processes, you need to implement a Queue
something like this could work

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np

def gen(q):
   x = np.random.normal(0, 500, 12500)
   q.put(x)

while true:
   q = multiprocessing.Queue()
   x1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=gen, arg=(q,))
   x2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=gen, arg=(q,))

   x1.start()
   x2.start()
   y1 = q.get()
   y2 = q.get()
   x1.join()
   x2.join()
   if(y1...y2): #condition comparing elements from array y1 and y2
      break
```

Comment: It should be 'args' instead of 'arg'